# laser_scan_matcher failed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using gmapping and it is working fine with fake odometry. But now I wanted to use laser_scan_matcher to get better odometry data. I have a .bag file with the scan data and tf between laser and baseLink and the fake odometry. Gmapping is working fine, but laser_scan_matcher throws some error:

```
[ WARN] [1349336438.204428307]: Could not get initial transform from base to laser frame, Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1349336437.203845202 but the latest data is at time 1349256596.739311565, when looking up transform from frame [/laser] to frame [/base_link]
[ WARN] [1349336438.204658155]: Skipping scan
[ WARN] [1349336439.213438249]: Could not get initial transform from base to laser frame, Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1349336438.204962942 but the latest data is at time 1349256596.739311565, when looking up transform from frame [/laser] to frame [/base_link]
[ WARN] [1349336439.213652382]: Skipping scan
```

Why is this? I mentioned, that the latest data time is not changing.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45078/laser_scan_matcher-failed/) by [darkchris90](https://answers.ros.org/users/3307/darkchris90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-10-04**:
How are you playing the bag? Are you setting rosparam use_sim_time to true? (you should be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The laser_scan_matcher waits for 1 second for the tf. If it doesn''t get it, it gives up on the current scan, and tries again when the next scan arrives. This looks like a problem with the timestamps in the bag, or maybe improper use of "use_sim_time"

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2